# How to deal with phone dropped in water

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 6s and this is the second time I have dropped my phone into water. I managed to get it replaced the first time (this was only a few weeks ago) but it happened again. It initially didn't seem to be as bad as it was before so I'm hoping this can somehow be fixed.

I dropped it in the sink and there wasn't much water in there so I didn't think it would be that damaged. I was relieved to hear the music working on it, as this was not the case before, but it was quiet and muffled. So I placed it in some rice for a day but it seems to just be getting worse. The phone keeps putting down the volume by itself now and I cannot hear any music at all as when I keep putting the volume up it just goes back down. Should I just keep it there for a couple of more days or go back to the shop and buy a new one?

Comment: Step one: take it out of the water. Step two: turn off phone and do not use. Step three: place phone in bag of rice for weeks. Step four:  STOP USING PHONE NEAR WATER.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to take it to a 3rd-party repair store to get it cleaned, there's a chance that they can repair corrosion caused by water damage.